# Python access variable by two different files

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

Is it possible to read a variable from script a.py with a independently executed script b.py

Example:
a.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time

i = 0

def run():
    global i
    print(i)
    i = i+1

def get_i():
    return i
    
def main():
    pass        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":                  
    while True:
        run()        
        time.sleep(5)

print("Stopped")
```

b.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import a

print(a.get_i())
```

If b.py is executed it will print 0 but I want it to print the current state of *i* as set in a.py, so *i* has to be greater than 0.

I tried already with an extra c.py where *i* is saved as global variable an then c.py is imported in a.py and b.py but it is the same behaviour: b.py prints the initial value of *i* and not the value which is set in a.py

Notice: a.py is started before b.py and is still running because of the while loop and then b.py is executed.

Comment: From my understanding you ARE printing _i_ from a.py. What you're NOT doing is setting it's value in a.py. Since you are calling a.py as an import, your _if_ is not ever being run

Comment: Ok maybe i missed a point. a.py is started before b.py and is still running because of the while loop and then b.py is executed.

Comment: @HansDampf So, you're running two different processes simultaniously and want to share data between them?

Comment: I have a.py which is setting a variable all the time. And then I have b.py which is executed at a random time after the start of a.py and that b.py should get the variable which is set in a.py

Answer (score 0):

In `a.py` you create variable `i` with value of `0`. This is what being imported inside `b.py` (btw, you can even just do `import a; a.i`, this will do the same).

Nothing changes state of this variable, as `run` in `a.py` in only *declared*, not being run. If you want this to mutate your variable, you can either run this from `b.py`:

```
from a import run, get_i
run()
print(get_i())
```

Or you can execute `run` in `a.py`. This is bad practice in 99%, and you should really know why you need this, if you will do so:

```
# a.py
i = 0

def run():
    ...

run()
```

This way `run` will be executed during import time, as python simply execute everything in file during import.

Comment: If he really want to just import all of a... he can do a.run() as well

Comment: And is there a way to get the varibale in b.py from a.py if a.py is NOT imported in b.py?

Comment: Not directly. If you want to get data after some time after running script without calling it directly, you need to store this state somewhere. Lets say, in file on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is by using a common config file (e.g. config.txt) to store the *i* values.
A minimal example of what I mean is the following:

**a.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

i = 0

# create a config.txt in the same directory

def get_i():
    with open('config.txt', 'r') as f:
        last_i = f.read().splitlines()[-1]
    return last_i

def run():
    global i
    while True: 
        i += 1
        with open('config.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(str(i)+'\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit(0)
```

and **b.py** is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print __import__('a').get_i()
```

Though this is a *very simple example* and what you are trying to do **is a bad practice** in programming. Also as I said this is a very simple example, but in real life problems accessing common resources is not that simple.